# OSGi/Equinox Bundle Can't Find File

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox

I am writing two OSGi bundles using Eclipse and Equinox.

My first bundle, Bundle A, is in Project: Bundle A. My second Bundle B, is in Bundle B.

Bundle B loads a file server.cfg, which is located in it's project root directory (IE: workspace/Bundle B/server.cfg).

When I execute the OSGi framework, it is executing from the workspace/ directory and Bundle B cannot find server.cfg, thus, throwing an error. It is looking in workspace/server.cfg rather than workspace/Bundle B/server.cfg.

I can change the Working Directory to be Bundle B, which will find the server.cfg file. However, Bundle B cannot then find any of Bundle A's classes, thus, throwing an error.

I'm not really sure how I can inform Bundle B of the location of the file, while still being able to access Bundle A's classes from B.

I'm using Eclipse 3.6.2.

---

Update:
I've solved this issue by doing the following:
Setting the Working Directory to Bundle B and then exporting/importing Bundle A in the manifest files. This seemed to work.

Comment: What do you mean Bundle B cannot find Bundle A's classes when you change the working directory? Why are you loading classes from the working directory? This doesn't sound much like OSGi to me.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to set the working directory.  Try:

```
URL url = bundleB.getEntry("server.cfg");
File file = new File(FileLocator.toFileURL(url).getFile());
```

Also make sure your server.cfg file is exported in your build.properties (Build tab of the Manifest Editor).